# ArgumentException - Value does not fall within the expected range. when searching value in list

Tags: c#, list, search, windows-runtime, argumentexception

I am trying to get an item from a list by searching the list by propery.
i have list of Books and i have a search option by book title, author, genre etc.

the search method i got from my teacher so its not my own.
i've breakpoint it to see that it works, and it does.
it recognized the  book i wanted by the property i was searching it, but when i want to display the book with all its info i get an exception "Value does not fall within the expected range".

this is the search method i'm using:

```
    public AbstractItem Find(Func<AbstractItem, bool> condition)
    {
        AbstractItem result = null;

        foreach (var item in List)
        {
            if (condition(item))
            {
                result = item;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

which later turned like this:(for each propery)

```
    public AbstractItem FindByTitle(string title)
    {
        return Find((item) => item.Title == title);
    }
```

i dont know why i'm getting this exception. please help me out with it

thank you!

so this is the way i add the result of the find method to the ListView:

```
 private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //search by title, author, year, genre
        //if found by one parameter or several - show in listBox
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tBoxSearchName.Text))
        {
            listViewSearchResult.ItemsSource = LibMng.FindByTitle(tBoxSearchName.Text);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tBoxSearchYear.Text))
        {
            listViewSearchResult.ItemsSource = LibMng.FindByYear(DateTime.Parse(tBoxSearchYear.Text));
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tBoxSearchGenre.Text))
        {
            //listViewSearchResult.ItemsSource = LibMng.FindByGenre(tBoxSearchGenre.Text);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tBoxSearchAuthor.Text))
        {
            listViewSearchResult.ItemsSource = LibMng.FindByAuthor(tBoxSearchAuthor.Text);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself.

Comment: So, the exception is thrown when trying to show the properties of the found "book"? Then, why are you showing the Find methods instead of the "DisplayProperties" one?

Comment: i'm not sure i understood what you're saying so i'll try to explain better what i meant.

the find method search the list by property of the book. if i want to search a book written by "George Orwell" i want it to find all books where the Author is George Orwell and display them in a ListView.

when i type "George Orwell" in the TextBox the program freaze and i get this exception.

sorry if i'm not following complitly the site rule. It is only my second question in the site yet so be Patient

Comment: What I meant is that both find methods seems just fine to me. So the problem must be anywhere else in your code, maybe when you are trying to add the found book to the ListView. So that's the code we need to see to help you

Comment: @Dolev, What is the 'List'?

Comment: @Mukesh Modhvadiya  What do you mean "What is the List"?

The list is a list of item of types i created class for, like book, magazine etc  that each have a title, author, published date etc. Just like a real library preety much

Comment: You should have added "wpf" to the tags,as i assume your project is wpf,am i right?

Comment: You would think so but no. my school teach us using Winrt not Wpf

Comment: Does your code really compile? `ItemsSource` should only allow a `IEnumerable<T>`, and your `FindByTitle` method returns just an `AbstractItem`.

Comment: yeah my code compiles and works fine until i hit the search button and expect to see the reasult of the search in the listView.

AbstractItem is a class i writen from which my other classes that i create instances of like "Book", "Magazine", "Journal" will Inherit from it.
In the AbstractItem Class i've put all the properties of the derived classes i created

Comment: Ok, in UWP `ItemsSource` accepts an object, you are right. Then maybe the problem is in the listview, did you set the `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` properties?

Comment: i dont think so.  i'm a beginner in programming and most of what i do is based on searching on the web to find way to get what i want to work.

i am using binding with the propeties name of the items in the list if that's what you meant.

for each binding i have a TextBlok with inside it i have the binding with one propety name